# Image icon not showing in Ribbon Command using officejs Exceladd-in

Tags: office-js

**Excel online version**

We are trying to set images (.PNG files) in Ribbon commands. When we trying to set images through manifest file, image icons on commands (Login button) are being displayed correctly for single line ribbon. But images are hiding when set to multi line ribbon. Please find Attached screen shot for both scenarios. Kindly advise to show images all the time for Ribbon commands.

**Desktop version**

For Desktop version it is showing like pentagon icon instead of imported images.

[DesktopLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFKVL.png)

[SingleLineRibbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3rRZ.png)

[MultiLineRibbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7jx8.png)

Comment: separate different size icons are needed as described in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-icons-fresh#icon-size-recommendations-and-requirements

Comment: Thank you.. due to incorrect configuration was facing now resolved based on documentation and samples